# M2 - Admin related product, grid columns

Tags: admin, product-attribute, grid

In Magento 2 you can select your own attributes you want to show on the normal product grid in the admin. But when you are editing a product and want to add some related product, all the attributes will be shown as a column on there...

Is there a way to change what is visible there? I have over 700 attributes so you can imagine how many columns are visible now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion . That you create a atribute set for attributes. then attributes are  show on product if you chhose that attribute set.